# Which version of .NET 4.0 is needed for web site hosting? Client or Full?

Tags: .net-4.0

Simple question -> for dedicated website hosting, do i need to download and install the full ASP.NET 4.0 package, or just the client.

I understand the client is required for end users who need the .NET framework for their windows *form* applications.

But i'm not sure for a web hosting sceanrio.

Also, don't worry about talking about x86 or x64 - i understand the differences with the packages, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.Net runtime is only included with the Full installation.

(This is one of the biggest savings of the client profile; ASP.Net is large)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would need the full. The client profile specifically excludes ASP.NET.